# Objective-C condition inside cellForRowAtIndexPath for cell imageView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have this block of code, what I am trying to do is if the NSString of type is equal to Directory, I want the cell to have an image, if it does not, no image, but every cell item returns with an image :( What am i doing wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *elements = [[[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"FTP\\"];

    NSString *type = [[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Type"];

    cell.textLabel.text = elements[1];

    if([type  isEqual: @"Directory"]){
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FolderImage"];
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String comparsion should be done in other way

Try:

```
if([type  isEqualToString: @"Directory"]){
       cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FolderImage"];
} else {
       cell.imageView.image = NULL;
}
```

Comment: That did not work :( still getting an image for all cells

Comment: Maybe you forget to reset your image? So you mean all items displaying with image, except neccesary one?

Answer (score 2):

The same cells get re-used at different index paths. So you need to explicitly set the image to nil in an else condition:

```
if([type isEqualToString: @"Directory"]){
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FolderImage"];
}
else {
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
}
```